# How to deploy a RESTEasy Application in TomCat 9.0？

Tags: java, tomcat, resteasy, web.xml

I do search lot of topics about that,some  tell me use the resteasy-servlet-intialler,some use the RestEasyBootstrap,but it can't work and just respond the 404 page.It drive my crazy.Can you help me out?

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.restfully.shop.services.ShoppingApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and this is the simply Application:

```
@ApplicationPath("/services")
public class ShoppingApplication extends Application {

    private Set<Object> singletons =new HashSet<Object>();
    private Set<Class<?>> empty=new HashSet<Class<?>>();

    public ShoppingApplication()
    {
        singletons.add(new CustomerResource());
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        return empty;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        return singletons;
    }
}
```

and here is the gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile group:'org.jboss.resteasy',name:'resteasy-jaxrs',version:'3.1.2.Final'
    compile group:'org.jboss.resteasy',name:'resteasy-jackson-provider',version:'3.1.2.Final'
    compile group:'org.jboss.resteasy',name:'resteasy-guice',version:'3.1.2.Final'
    compile group: 'org.jboss.resteasy',name:'resteasy-servlet-initializer',version:'3.1.2.Final'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `@ApplicationPath` annotation, because it's redundant due to your web.xml configuration.

And change web.xml to:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
    <param-value>/services</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.restfully.shop.services.ShoppingApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Notice the updated url-pattern.

Comment: It doesn't work though.I delete the repeated annotation,and update the context-param as well as url-pattern .I think there must be some tips or log infos from the Tomcat logging,but it just show deploy sucessfully and when I try to access it,It shows 404

Comment: but there is a info "org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs"

Comment: @GyxLove521 What's the URL you're trying to access? And please update the question with the updated _web.xml_ file and the resource class.